# Campaign Type Not showing up in Picklist Field

Tags: community, leads, campaign

I've created a new campaign type, but it is not showing on the campaign picklist selection.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you've made the new picklist value available to the Record Type that you're using to validate creation, i.e. Customize -> Object -> Record Types, then click the name of the Record Type it's not appearing for. Select the trouble picklist field and add the value to be available.  If that doesn't solve your issue, does it have a dependency on another picklist?